# How can I append <p> to the start and </p> to the end of a string if it's missing?

Tags: c#, regex

I have users who enter data with or without the `<p> and </p>.` If they enter without then how can I determine this and then add it to my string? Would it be most efficient to use something like regex or is there an even easier way?

Note that I am only concerned about the start and end of the string and not about anything in between.

Comment: why would a user EVER be entering <p> ... </p>

Comment: What if the user enters only one of the two?

Comment: If HTML is permissible (e.g. a rich editor), then you may have more scenarios to address such as sanitization but also the general well-formedness of the input as either a fragment or a document. In other words, a parser may be very beneficial.

Comment: If you *do* use a starts/ends with string method, at least use the comparison options for case-insensitivity.

Comment: And what happens if he enters <P>...</P>? (upper case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your needs, I'd use something very easy like

```
var s = your_user_string;
if (!s.StartsWith("<p>") && !s.EndsWith("</p>"))
  s = String.Format("<p>{0}</p>", s);
```

**UPDATED** after OP comment:

```
var s = !input.StartsWith("<p>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && 
        !input.EndsWith("</p>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        ? String.Format("<p>{0}</p>", input)
        : input;
```

Comment: I like this answer very much. Is there a way that I can make it so this happens using a ? : and keep it all on the one line?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you've done all the relevant trimming & case checking:

```
if (!s.StartsWith("<p>")) {
    s = "<p>" + s;
}

if (!s.EndsWith("</p>")) {
    s += "</p>";
}
```

Comment: I think you mean to use the instance methods of `string` (not a static one), e.g. `s.StartsWith("<p>")`

Answer (score 2):

`regex` could be a nice solution
you can check for

```
^\s*<p>
```

for the beginning of the line and

```
</p>\s*$
```

for the end of line, and if you don encounter a match then you can add them manually.

Comment: @Tim Because it's a regex when there's built-in StartsWith and EndsWith methods.

Comment: FWIW, a compiled regex can be very, very fast but the string methods are internal calls against highly optimized libraries. Regardless of which one is faster, you should be careful making blanket statements like "regex are the easiest and most efficient solution".

Comment: I agree; don't be hung up on the fact one person downvoted your answer. Overall community opinion is meant to weigh in on an answer's score. At least one person (me) found a regex to be overdoing it. Other people find it OK. That's how it should be. Your score is the result of those two sides (among others) weighing in, and your reputation is going to benefit much more from upvotes than it will be damaged by downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

C# strings have **StartsWith()** and **EndsWith()** methods. If your string is named **input**...

```
if (!input.StartsWith("<p>")) input = "<p>" + input;
if (!input.EndsWith("</p>")) input += "</p>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this;

```
string input = "UserInput";

                if (input.StartsWith("<p>") == true && input.EndsWith("</p>") == true)
                {
                    //Nothing to do here.
                }
                else if (input.StartsWith("<p>") == true && input.EndsWith("</p>") == false)
                {
                    input = input + "</p>";//Append </p> at end.
                }
                else if (input.StartsWith("<p>") == false && input.EndsWith("</p>") == true)
                {
                    input = "<p>" + input;//Append </p> at beginning.
                }
                else if (input.StartsWith("<p>") == false && input.EndsWith("</p>") == false)
                {
                    input = "<p>" + input + "</p>";//Append </p> at end and <p> at beginning.
                }
```

Comment: This is overcomplicating it a bit. There are only really two cases needing checking here - see the other answers (e.g. mine, Evan's and Marco's)